# How to parse any URL/URI in Java?

Tags: java, parsing, url

I am searching a way for parsing URL/URIs in Java without having to worry about Exceptions for common URLs. The Java integrated way I know are using `java.net.URI` respectively `java.net.URL`.

Each of these classes have major draw backs:

- `java.net.URL` can not handle custom protocols/schemes and fails therefore with URLs like `idontcare://bla.com/test`
- `java.net.URI` has no problems with custom protocols/schemes but it fails if for example the query part contains an "illegal character" (a special character that is not URL encoded). Therefor it failes for example in an URL like `https://bla.example.org/css?family=Roboto:300|Roboto:300,400,500,700&lang=de`

Is there a universal and non-resticted (does not throw errors for cases as presented above) way to parse URLs in Java?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters

Comment: @ y_ug That question is about the opposite direction - it is about building a correctly encoded URL, I have a `String` that contains an url and want just access it's components like host name and protocol/scheme.

Comment: I see. Then those who do not want extra dependencies (like `UriComponents` from Spring Framework) can write custom protocols/schemes handler(s) and/or implement `URLStreamHandlerFactory` and enable them via `java.protocol.handler.pkgs` property or register with `URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [`UriComponents`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponents.html) from Spring Framework capable of handling both URIs:

```java
String uri = ...
UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(uri).build();
```

You can check the [code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.java) to see what it does.

Comment: If you are on a non-Spring application the library `org.springframework:spring-web` and it's dependencies are a big bunch of code (~3.4MB at the moment for 5.2.3) just for parsing URIs. But the Regex pattern `URI_PATTERN` in the linked code and the `fromUriString(String)` method seems to be of great value. And it is under Apache 2 license :)